# Analysis limit.....

Tags: real-analysis

Just need help/guidance with (c)

(a) Let $I$ be an interval, let $c$ be a point of $I$, and let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be two functions,
each of which is defined everywhere on $I$ except possibly at $c$. Assume that
$f_1(x) = f_2(x)$ for every $x \neq c$, and that $L = \lim_{x\to c} f_1(x)$ exists. Prove that
$\lim_{x\to c}f_2(x)$ exists and equals $L$. (This involves thinking carefully about the
definition of a limit.)

(b) Let $I$ be an interval, let $c$ be a point of $I$. Let $f_1$ be a function which is defined
and continuous on $I$, and let $f_2$ be a function which is defined everywhere on $I$
except possibly at $c$. Assume that $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$ for every $x \neq c$. Prove that
$\lim_{x\to c} f_2(x)$ exists and equals $f_2(c)$.

(c) The function
$f(x) = \frac{(x^3)-8}{(x^2)-4}$
is defined at every point of the interval $(0; 1)$ except for the point 2. By applying
the result of part (b) with $f_2 = f$ and with a suitable choice of $f_2$, prove that
$\lim_{x\to 2} f(x)$ exists, and nd its value. (The result of problem 3(b) above, and
results proved in class, will be needed here. You may NOT use l'H^opital's Rule
since we have not proved it or even defined derivatives yet. Furthermore, such
an approach would be circular since the calculation involved in this problem is
similar to the ones that will be needed to justify derivative calculations later in
the course.)

the result of 3b... Let g be a function which is defined and continuous on an interval I, and never
takes the value 0. Prove that 1=g(x) is continuous. Combine this a result proved
in class to show that if f is another function which is defined and continuous on
I, then f(x)=g(x) is continuous.

Comment: There are directions how to properly write mathematics in this site in the FAQ section.

Comment: [How to ask a homework question.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)

Comment: Well, some spacing would help but the question's now clearer. Now, what have you done so far? What's your effort? Where are you stuck?

Comment: did a and b, just need help with c

Comment: Okay, it seems like (a), 3(b) (which is presumably different from (b)) and "a result proved in class" are not necessary for (c).  So why include them in your question?  We don't need to know the structure of your homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (c) you only need some basic algebra and apply the results in (a)-(b):

$$\frac{x^3-8}{x^2-4}=\frac{\color{red}{(x-2)}(x^2+2x+4)}{\color{red}{(x-2)}(x+2)}=\frac{x^2+2x+4}{x+2}\xrightarrow[x\to 2]{}\frac{4+4+4}{2+2}=\ldots$$

You now complete all the rest...